# Search within input tag with Datatables

Tags: jsp, datatables, el

I recently discovered DataTables (http://datatables.net/) and have been playing around with its features.

I'm running into a bit of trouble with the search feature. I'm using DataTables in a JSP webapp, where I use expression language (EL) to pull and display information stored in the session.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<table id="list" class="table table-hover results">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="elt" items="${listCandidates}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="ViewFullCandidateProfileServlet">
                        <a href="#">
                            <input type="hidden" name="candidateID" value="${elt.candidateID }">
                            <input type="submit" name="View Profile" value="${elt.firstName} ${elt.lastName}">
                        </a>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The search fails to pick up data within the value attribute in the input tags. How can I direct it to look there?

Appreciate any pointers, Cheers!

Comment: Are you implying that when you hardcode the table and inputs in plain HTML, everything works fine? This is technically not possible as JSP is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator, and JS/jQuery works merely on the HTML DOM tree and knows absolutely nothing about the server side code responsible for generating that HTML output, such as JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom search functionality for your datatables like this:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function(value) {
    return $(value).val(); //will search in value attibute of element
};
```

and then attach your search functionality to datatables:

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{ "type": "html-input", "targets": [0, 3] }] 
});
```

Here is also a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL52ecjs/3/)

Thanks to @davidkonrad