# JQuery DataTables Search within Input/Select With Complex DOM Structure

Tags: jquery, datatables

The following two threads deal with a problem similar to mine, but they haven't resolved my problem because they are too simplistic,

[JQuery Datatables search within input and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852497/jquery-datatables-search-within-input-and-select)

[Search within input tag with Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001142/search-within-input-tag-with-datatables)

I have a DataTable consisting of input fields, Text/Select inputs. To enable the Search function inside them, I know I can do

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function(value) {
    return $(value).val(); //will search in value attibute of element
};
```

and then attach

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{ "type": "html-input", "targets": [2, 3, 4] }] 
});
```

But this assumes that I have a simple DOM structure where the fields are directly under my `TD` tag. This was the original simple example from one of the links.

https://jsfiddle.net/dL52ecjs/3/

I did a Fork from the Fiddle where I changed the DOM as follows:

- **Name**: Wrap inside a `<DIV>`, and also add a 2nd Input in the same cell. The Search should apply to both.
- **Age**: Wrap inside a `<DIV>`

New Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9vL1yukp/1/

Doesn't work anymore. My columns can individually have different layers or additional controls.

Actually, it broke even when I added just a `<DIV>` wrapper, so even a minor modification (without any new controls) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **Pilan**'s answer ([JQuery DataTables Search within Input/Select With Complex DOM Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977212/jquery-datatables-search-within-input-select-with-complex-dom-structure/50977609#50977609)) but with some extra tweaks, and also refactoring to allow both Search and Sort, here's the final answer.

Strategy: First define a utility function that returns a **"representative String" for a given TD cell**. Then, use it in **both the Search and Sort**, to support both operations.

```
// Define the custom utility function that brings back a "Representative String" for a TD for DataTables' Search & Sort
function getRepresentativeStringForTDContent(el) {

    // Will store concenatenated string for this TD cell
    var all_search_values = "";

    // NOTE: "el" is the content of TD, which could be either 
    //      (1) input field(s) themselves -- one or multiple, or 
    //      (2) wrapping element(s) in which we need to find() -- one or multiple
    $(el).each(function (index) {
        var inputsInput = $(this).is('input') ? $(this) : $(this).find('input');
        var inputsSelect = $(this).is('select') ? $(this) : $(this).find('select');

        inputsInput.each( function( i, e) {
            // Text Inputs added by value
            all_search_values += $(e).val();
        });
        inputsSelect.each( function( i, e) {
            // Select Inputs added by Selected Option text (not value)
            all_search_values += $(e).find('option:selected').text(); 
        });    

    });

    return all_search_values;   
}
```

Now, the customized DataTable Search (and Sort) will use this Representative Value as follows:

**1. Search**

```
// Define the DataTable custom Search function for Input/Select fields
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function(el) {
    return getRepresentativeStringForTDContent(el);
};
```

**2. Sort**

```
 // Define the DataTable custom Sort function for Input/Select fields
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['html-input'] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return getRepresentativeStringForTDContent($(td).html());
        });
    };
```

Apply the 2 customized Search & Sort functions to the DataTable:

```
// DataTable creation
var table = $("#exampleTable").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { "type": "html-input", "targets": [3, 4, 5] },  // Search Logic
       { "orderDataType": "html-input", type: "string", "targets": [3, 4, 5] }  // Sort Logic
    ] 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try get a **"total value"**

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['html-input'] = function(el) {
    var inputs = $(el).find('input[value]');
    var all_values = "";
    inputs.each( function( i, e) {
        all_values += $(e).val();
    } );
    return all_values;
};
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       { "type": "html-input", "targets": [0, 3] }
    ] 
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vL1yukp/30/)

**UPDATE**

You can extend this for selects, or whatever you like

[fiddle for selects aswell](https://jsfiddle.net/9vL1yukp/32/)

if you want to add another type of value you want to check, just select the elements and add the property you want to check to `all_values`

```
all_values <-- (existing filled with input values for example)

// Search in image titles
var elements = $(el).find('img[title]');
elements.each( function( i, e) {
    all_values += $(e).attr('title');
} );

// Search in Link hrefs
var elements = $(el).find('a[href]');
elements.each( function( i, e) {
    all_values += $(e).attr('href');
} );

// etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks, there is one problem here. We're missing the `Select` (dropdown) fields. However, we can't do a similar thing with `var inputsSelect = $(el).find('select[value]');` because  the Select's Value is not directly in the tag, but on the Option. I'm working on a solution, but if you find one also let me know.

Comment: There is also another issue. With Selects, if I were to search by Value, often it's irrelevant and hidden and I should be searching by Text. I'll incorporate both of these Select issues.

Comment: Thanks. I came up with the solution below based on your post.